# displaying column names in emails and structure of email

Tags: c#, database, email

so I am trying to send an email with info gotten from a database.  I have a problem because when i send the email the column name doesn't show.  Also how can i structure the email to show like a database meaning column name and under it the info then the next column. below is my code. as you can see in the bottom i did columns.tostring but isnt working. any help is appreciated

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Net.Mail;
using System.Net;

namespace sql_connection
{
class Program
{
 static void Main(string[] args)
{                             
    string conn = null;
    SqlConnection connection;
    conn= ("Data Source=database\\SQL2012;Initial Catalog=jobs;User ID=user;Password=passs");

    connection = new SqlConnection(conn);
    try{

        connection.Open();
        Console.WriteLine("Connection Open!");
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT [jobs].[dbo].[table hours].whd_Date,[jobs].[dbo].[table hours].whd_FromTime,[jobs].[dbo].[table hours].whd_ToTime, [jobs].[dbo].[table hours].whd_User,[jobs].[dbo].[table login].login_Email FROM [jobs].[dbo].[table hours]INNER JOIN [jobs].[dbo].[table login] ON [jobs].[dbo].[table hours].whd_User = [jobs].[dbo].[table login].login_LoginId WHERE  DATEDIFF(DAY,[whd_Date],GETDATE())<=7 AND   (whd_ToTime = '' OR whd_ToTime IS NULL) AND(whd_User=login_LoginId)");
        cmd.Connection = connection;
        SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        var columns = Enumerable.Range(0, reader.FieldCount).Select(reader,GetName).ToList();


        var list = new List<string>();

        while(reader.Read())
        {


              var s = string.Format("{4},{3},{2}, {1}, {0}",
               reader["whd_ToTime"] == DBNull.Value? "NULL" : reader["whd_ToTime"].ToString(), 
               reader["whd_FromTime"] == DBNull.Value? "NULL" : reader  ["whd_FromTime"].ToString(), 
               reader["whd_Date"].ToString(), 
               reader["whd_User"].ToString(),
               reader["login_Email"].ToString());
              Console.WriteLine("\t", columns.ToArray()));
            Console.WriteLine(s);
            list.Add(s);




        }

        var sb = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (var s in list)
        {
            sb.AppendLine(s);
        }



        connection.Close();

         MailAddress to = new MailAddress("email@gmail.com");


        MailAddress from = new MailAddress("email@gmail.com");

        MailMessage mail = new MailMessage(from, to);


        mail.Subject = ("missed punch clock");

        mail.Body = sb.ToString(); columns.ToString();

        SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
        smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
        smtp.Port = 587;

        smtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(
            "email@gmail.com", "passworrd");
        smtp.EnableSsl = true;
        Console.WriteLine("Sending email..");
        smtp.Send(mail);
    } 




    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }                       
}
}
}
```

Comment: Your best bet would be to build a `HTML table` containing the data you want to display. This can then be set as the body of the email. Just make sure to set `IsHtml = true;`

Comment: **columns.ToString();** <-- This isn't doing anything.

Comment: @JeffreyWieder do you know of a good link to learn to do this and ishtml isnt working tells me is does not exist in the current context

Comment: @JWiley i realise that. thats why i need help figuring out how to do it.

Comment: @bobby How to do what? Simply putting in a floating line of code that does nothing isn't an attempt at it. At the least, try appending it to your email body. `mail.Body = String.Concat(sb.ToString(), columns.ToString());` formatting is up to you.

Comment: @JWiley i tried putting that but this line came up System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]

Comment: that's because `columns` is a `List`. Using `ToString()` on a list does not give you the contents of the list, but the `List` object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calling `ToString()` on a list does not give you the list contents. 
Use this instead:

```
string columnNames = string.Join(',', columns);
mail.Subject = ("missed punch clock");        
mail.Body = String.Concat(sb.ToString(), columnNames );
```